# Is there a way to write a lambda expression inside an IF with everything captured?

Tags: c++, lambda

It's my understanding that if I use the syntax [&] in a lambda expression, then my lambda expression has access to surrounding variables and parameters of the function.

Therefore, I tried to write the following (simplified) code

```
if ( [&]() 
     {
        bool b = false;
        return b;
     }
   )
  {
     // Do something in TRUE part of if statement
  }
```

but I get the error "Value of type 'lambda at...' is not contextually convertible to 'bool'

Would appreciate some insight into this issue.

Many thanks,
D

Comment: I'm reaaaally curious if you have some actual use case for this, and why you wouldn't just build your lambda outside the `if` (right above).

Comment: There doesn't have to be an actual use case. Someone wants to learn, and practice, how lambdas work, and understand what they're all about. There's nothing wrong with trying some slightly wacky stuff, as part of the learning process. Nothing wrong with that, whatsoever.

Comment: @Nicu   I do have a use case but explaining it seemed unnecessary

Comment: @Sam Indeed --- and that's something I tell people all the time. We learn by experiment.

Comment: my use case:         assert([&](){int nop; AImage_getNumberOfPlanes(image, &nop); return nop == 1;}());
Yes, just syntactic sugar (and more for the sake of learning), but here the lambda is clearly useful only inside the assert, so it makes sense to try to encapsulate it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to *call* the lambda you're constructing. It will not be called implicitly.

```
if ([&]() { /*...*/ return b; }()) {
    //                         ^^ call the lambda
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Duh! Thank you so much.